# Lambda inconsistently times out when connecting to RDS PostgreSQL database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I've created a Lambda that connects inconsistently to a PostgreSQL database in RDS.

When it works, it connects and completes the query in a small amount of time. Less than 100ms, usually only 20ms. I can execute this lambda ten or twenty times and it will work fine. Eventually though, it gets stuck trying to connect to the database.

The connection will time out eventually. I have set the timeout to be thirty seconds. Extending it doesn't seem to make a difference.

When it does get stuck connecting, I can sometimes try it half an hour later or so and it will be fine. Sometimes it will still fail, even after a day.

It usually works for a while when I upload a new zip. Sometimes, when it doesn't connect to the database immediately after the upload of a new zip, I can get it to work by editing the lambda in the AWS Lambda console and clicking Deploy from there.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before? What am I doing wrong?
I'm new to node and Lambdas. I created a lambda in C# as well and get the same behaviour.

The database instance is correctly provisioned and has only a small number of connections.

Here is a sample of the code. I don't use the dbConfig as I have stored them as environment variables. The zip uploaded to Lambda contains this file and the node_modules folder for 'pg' and its dependancies.

```
'use strict';
var pg = require('pg');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  var dbConfig = {
    username: '<username>',
    password: '<password>',
    database: '<database>',
    host: '<database_endpoint>',
    };
  var client = new pg.Client(dbConfig);
    
  console.log('Waiting to connect'); 
  await client.connect();
  console.log('Connected'); 
  
  console.log('Querying the database');
  var res = await client.query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books;'); // 'books' is a table in the database
  console.log(res);
  
  await client.end();
  console.log('Connection closed');
};
```

Using pg.Pool instead of pg.Client hasn't helped.

Moving the connection code outside of the handler only seems to work with callbacks. Callbacks don't seem to work well with Lambdas anymore.

Comment: Is lambda and PostgeSQL RDS is in the same account / VPC ?

Comment: This can also occur if you configure the Lambda function to run in VPC and on multiple subnets and one of the subnets has an incorrectly configured route table.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Comment: Another cause may be the port. Check in the security group rules that the port 5432 is available for connections

Comment: J. Pelaez, not really. If the port was not available it would never have connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nikhil B's comment solved this. I removed a subnet with a bad route table and the connection stabilised.

No more timeouts waiting to connect to the db.